# Indexing into vector

Tags: matlab

Can someone please explain why in example A the result is 1x6 vector (which makes sense and was what I was expecting) whereas in example B the result is 1x4 vector?

In example B if I predefine the size of newvec to be a 1x6 vector then the result is the correct 1x6 vector. Just not understanding what is going on.

**Example A**

```
vec = [0 2 3 0 5 0]     %1x6
newvec(vec == 0) = 1    %produces a 1 x 6 vector
```

**Example B**

```
vec = [0 2 3 0 5 3]     %1 x 6
newvec(vec == 0) = 1    %produces a 1 x 4 vector
```

Comment: your example does not make sense. please add the correct code for the problem you have. the code you added always give a 1x6 vector

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro: not if you issue `clear newvec` before each example :)

Comment: +1 interesting question. The answers give you an idea of what's going on, but just to add something. If you don't have a vector in the workspace and create it by assigning so like `A(5) = 1` for example (where `A` didn't exist before), matlab will create A big enough to put `1` in the 5th element and fill the rest with zeros. Try it. Also you can expand a matrix this way too for example `x=1:5; x(10) = 1`, try that & you should see it fills elements 6 - 9 with zeros. I guess you could kind of think of your problem in a similar way, you told matlab to assign to positions 1 & 4 so it stops at 4

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Indeed if you do not have the variable or if you clear it it will change but in that case it is not a difference of example A and B. It is A with predefined variable or cleared variable. Therefore the question is not clear, but thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Dan for pointing out the error.

`vec == 0` produces a logical matrix. **Now if size of newvec is not defined**  then `newvec(vec==0) =1` will always create a new *row vector* newvec.

The following steps will decide the size of this `newvec`

```
temp1 = logical_matrix(:);
trailing_zeros = number of zeros after the occurrence of last `true` value in temp1
size(newvec) = [1, numel(logical_matrix) - trailing_zeros] ;
```

**When you predefine the size of `newvec`** then `newvec(v==0) = 1` cannot change the size of `newvec` , it only assigns `1` to the corresponding indices for which `vec==0` is `true`.

Comment: "will create a vector newvec whose size will be equal to the number of true(ones) values in the logical matrix" not true, `newvec` will be the size of the position of the last `true` value in your logical matrix, not the number of `true` values.

Comment: *"...whose size will be equal to the number of true(ones) values in the logical matrix , which in this case is 4"*, well that's not true now is it? Because the size of `newvec` in Example A is 1× 6, while there are only 3 `trues` in the original `vec`. The size of `newvec` depends on the position of the *last* `true`, which is rather strange.

Comment: @Nishant: I have been noticing that you sometimes make mistakes in your MATLAB syntax in your answers and comments.  Suggest that you actually use MATLAB and echo the output to the screen before writing your answers for the next time.  That way you don't mislead the OP as well as other people who read your answers.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for taking time to point out my mistakes,from now on I will take care of it

Comment: @Nishant: I hope I didn't come across as being condescending!  I appreciate your answers and they're quite insightful.  In fact I've learned a couple of things from you.... just looking out for you that's all :)

Comment: @rayryeng , Its completely fine , I really appreciate your concern. It's nice that you spare your time for the improvement of community. :)

Answer (score 4):

*Why*, we will never know. It's a design choice by The MathWorks, and IMHO, it indeed violates the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

It smells a bit of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) (in terms of RAM usage) and/or that MATLAB's internals do a call to `find` before the assignment, or something similar. But it's anyone's guess, really.

A more common way to do what you want, is this:

```
newvec = (vec == 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

If `newvec` doesn't exist when you call the second line, MATLAB only makes it as large as it needs to hold the indexes you're setting to `1`.

What you're actually doing is:

`newvec([1 4 6]) = 1;` or

`newvec([1 4]) = 1;`

Similarly if `vec` was actually a 2D/3D etc. matrix, `newvec` will come out as `1 x N`, where N is whatever the highest index number is, and not retain the shape of the original matrix.

So, in these cases you need to either:

1) preallocate `newvec` to be the size of `vec` first.

2) Do `newvec = (vec==0)` instead